# MVC Core can I change default laout for specific page?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I'm using a MVC Core RC2.

I see that the main HTML template is in the 'Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml' file and it's apply for all pages.

Is it possible to use a different template for a few pages?

I would like to make two pages look completely different than the rest of the site (eg. with no menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have at least two options:

1. Create second template and use it where you need,
2. Turn off the default template for pages where you need and enter the html code directly in this pages.

Path to template is stored in the variable `Layout`, so just paste code below on the top of your pages and change path:

```
@{
     Layout = "/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

You can change this path to another template or set as empty string which just turns off the default template.

**More information:**

- [MVC Core Layout](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/layout.html)
- [MVC Core Specifying a Layout](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/layout.html#specifying-a-layout)
- [How to change default MVC layout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911845/how-to-change-default-mvc-layout-page)